# MSAL Angular Library is returning access token in response

Tags: angular, oauth-2.0, azure-ad-msal, msal-angular

**Aim** - We need to transfer PDF file from S3 bucket to user's SharePoint location.

Our frontend is in Angular and backend is in .NET C# WebAPI.

We are using the MSAL library provided by Microsoft to perform the OAuth.

We are trying to implement a Authorization code flow with PKCE.

**Problem** - We are receiving the access token in the response of the following code even though, we have configured it to return code in response.

MSAL internally calls the token endpoint, not sure why?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VjuLo.png)

Solution we are looking for - We need want to exchange the access token in the frontend but in the backend, however, MSAL is exchanging it automatically. Can someone explain this behavior?

```
const codeVerifier = this.generateRandomCodeVerifier();
const codeChallenge = this.generateCodeChallenge(codeVerifier);
const request = {
    redirectUri: 'https://localhost:5001/api/authorizecallback',
    scopes: ["openid", 'profile'],
    prompt: 'consent',
    responseType: 'code',
    responseMode: 'query',
    codeChallenge: codeChallenge,
    codeChallengeMethod: 'S256'
};

this.authService.loginPopup(request).subscribe(
    (response) => {
        if (response) {
        }
    },
    (err) => {
    },
    () => {
    }
);
```

We have already tried to change the configuration, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: If you read the documentation Angular MSAL is to "enable authentication in Angular Web Applications without backend servers".  You should have been tipped off this wasn't right if you had to provide the secret key to the frontend.  You can incorporate the MSAL.NET package https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Identity.Client and have the redirect go to an angular route that captures and sends the code to the backend for exchange.

Comment: @possum we are not exposing the Secret key to the frontend. When using the MSAL library for Angular, even though MSAL is configured to return the 'auth code', it is returning the 'access token' and 'refresh token' in response. We are planning to perform the exchange in the backend.

Comment: If you don't need the secret key to exchange a code for a token something is worryingly misconfigured then.  That means anyone could impersonate your app and defeats the purpose of doing the exchange in the backend.